# How to close JOptionPane automatically?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, joptionpane

I have a `Thread` running and in the time while the `thread` working i want to display a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` saying that the application is working and after thread is stopped, `JOptionPane` will close automatically and `OK` button will be deactivated the whole time. My Main code :

```
class Index {
public static void main(String args[]) {
   NewThread ob1 = new NewThread("One");
   NewThread ob2 = new NewThread("Two");
   NewThread ob3 = new NewThread("Three");
    System.out.println("Thread One is alive: "+ ob1.t.isAlive());
    System.out.println("Thread Two is alive: "+ ob2.t.isAlive());
    System.out.println("Thread Three is alive: "+ ob3.t.isAlive());
   while (ob1.t.isAlive()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thread One is alive");
   }
    System.out.println("Thread One is alive: "+ ob1.t.isAlive());
    System.out.println("Thread Two is alive: "+ ob2.t.isAlive());
    System.out.println("Thread Three is alive: "+ ob3.t.isAlive());
    System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
}}
```

And when i run it the `JOptionPane` display but he won't close  automatically unless i pressed `OK` button.

```
class NewThread implements Runnable {
String name; 
Thread t;
    NewThread(String threadname) {
        this.name = threadname;
        this.t = new Thread(this, name);
        System.out.println("New thread: " + t);
        this.t.start(); // Start the thread
    } 
public void run() {
    try {
    for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");}
        System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Create your own `Dialog` without any buttons...make sure you set the `defaultCloseOperation` to `DO_NOTHING`
- Use a [`ProgressMonitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html)

### ProgressMonitor example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ProgressMonitor;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestProgress {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestProgress();
    }

    public TestProgress() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                new BackgroundWorker().execute();

            }

        });
    }

    public class BackgroundWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        private ProgressMonitor monitor;

        public BackgroundWorker() {
            addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if ("progress".equalsIgnoreCase(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                        if (monitor == null) {
                            monitor = new ProgressMonitor(null, "Processing", null, 0, 99);
                        }
                        monitor.setProgress(getProgress());
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            if (monitor != null) {
                monitor.close();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                setProgress(index);
                Thread.sleep(125);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

### Dialog Example

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestProgress {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestProgress();
    }

    public TestProgress() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                new BackgroundWorker().execute();

            }

        });
    }

    public class BackgroundWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        private JProgressBar pb;
        private JDialog dialog;

        public BackgroundWorker() {
            addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if ("progress".equalsIgnoreCase(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                        if (dialog == null) {
                            dialog = new JDialog();
                            dialog.setTitle("Processing");
                            dialog.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
                            gbc.weightx = 1;
                            gbc.gridy = 0;
                            dialog.add(new JLabel("Processing..."), gbc);
                            pb = new JProgressBar();
                            gbc.gridy = 1;
                            dialog.add(pb, gbc);
                            dialog.pack();
                            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                            dialog.setVisible(true);
                        }
                        pb.setValue(getProgress());
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            if (dialog != null) {
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                setProgress(index);
                Thread.sleep(125);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm kind of beginner i tried to make my own Dialog but i didn't get it how to set optionpane. is there a sample code ?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to take `monitor = new ProgressMonitor(null, "Processing", null, 0, 99);` out of the `void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)` method ? `monitor` can simply be initialized in the constructor.

Comment: @c0der What happens if `propertyChange` is never called?  You'd have a dangling reference ... or if it's called multiple times? For me, it just makes sense to use only when it's needed, but if you feel it would be better done another way, that's probably okay to ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
 JOptionPane msg = new JOptionPane("Mensagem de advertência", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    final JDialog dlg = msg.createDialog("Advertência");
    dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dlg.setVisible(false);
      }
    }).start();
    dlg.setVisible(true);
```