# Show progress bar after an action

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar

I want to show a progress bar after some action. 
The actual code is complex, but I've prepared a sample
I want the progress bar to fill the width of the frame, but I want it to have a specific/normal height and not fill the frame. How can I achieve this? 
It would be preferable if the layout of the frame didn't change (`BorderLayout`), because it might break something else on my actual code. If this can't be avoided then by all means, change it and I will see what comes of it.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SwingControlDemo
{

    public static int progress = 0;
    private JFrame mainFrame;

    public SwingControlDemo()
    {
        prepareGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
    {
        //BeautyEyeLNFHelper.frameBorderStyle = BeautyEyeLNFHelper.FrameBorderStyle.osLookAndFeelDecorated;
       // org.jb2011.lnf.beautyeye.BeautyEyeLNFHelper.launchBeautyEyeLNF();
        new SwingControlDemo();
    }

    private void prepareGUI()
    {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Java Swing Examples");
        mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                showProgressBarDemo();
            }
        });

        mainFrame.add(new JLabel("mplaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainFrame.add(startButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void showProgressBarDemo()
    {
        final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        controlPanel.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
        mainFrame.revalidate();
        mainFrame.repaint();

        final Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {   
                progress++;
                System.out.println(String.format("Completed %d%% of task.\n", progress));
                progressBar.setValue(progress);
                progressBar.setString(String.format("Completed %d%% of task.\n", progress));
            }
        });

        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The actual code is complex, but I've prepared a sample I want the progress bar to fill the width of the frame, but I want it to have a specific/normal height and not fill the frame.

You could use a `GridBagLayout`, for example

```
JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
controlPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
controlPanel.add(progressBar, gbc);
```

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

You might consider taking advantage of the frame's "glass pane", which would allow you to place content over the top of the `contentPane`, but without directly effecting it.  If you registered a `MouseListener` to it, you could even block mouse events get through to the `contentPane` itself.

Have a look at [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details

Also, depending on your needs, you might be able to use a `ProgressMonitor`, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632987/how-to-close-joptionpane-automatically/16633344#16633344)

Answer (score 3):

> but I want it to have a specific/normal height

If you want it to show at its `preferredSize` than add it to a JPanel that uses FlowLayout, and then add that JPanel to your BorderLayout-using JPanel (if you want to still have a BorderLayout in place). Note myself, I'd swap components using a CardLayout.