# How to get JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() by title and close it after x seconds?

Tags: java, user-interface, junit, timer

I have a JUnit Testclass that opens a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog with a message and a title. When the title is correct (which means when the title is the one I have defined in my method that's tested) it should close itself after x seconds. How can I do that? Any way to get a JOptionPane by it's title?

Comment: The title is the same YOU passed in the method, so nothing fancy here.

Comment: Seems like an additional thread might be helpful (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26161887/4852017)